# Windows 8 - This app can't open

Tags: windows-8

I am receiving the following error for all Windows 8 metro apps, it used to stop happening for at least a little while when I rebooted the machine, but now it persists. I tried creating another user account, and that account was unaffected. Is there anything I can do to repair my existing account?

[image: this app can't open. there's a problem with Music. Contact your system administrator about repairing or reinstalling it.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the app trouble shooter:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271185

Also do what is suggested. Uninstall the App, go to the Store->My Apps->Apps which are not installed and reinstall them.

[image]

[image]